# How do I clear a reactive array in Vue3 using composition?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-reactivity, vue-script-setup

I have the following in my project...

```
const basicRecords = reactive([]);
```

It basically just houses an array of objects. I want to be able to refresh this array, that would require me to remove all of the records and add them back. To do this I have done the following...

```
basicRecords.splice(0);
basicRecords.push(...recordResult.data);
```

This seems to work but also seems super hacky.

What is the proper way to reset a reactive array in Vue3?

Comment: Not hacky, that's legit JS code, could also be `length = 0`, It's more practical to use a ref for this purpose, as the answer suggests

Comment: What about `basicRecords.value = recordResult.data` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use `Object.assign` to keep it reactive :

```js
const basicRecords = reactive([]);

Object.assign(basicRecords, recordResult.data)
```

or define `basicRecords` as inner field of reactive state :

```js
const state = reactive({basicRecords : []});

state.basicRecords = recordResult.data
```

or with `ref` :

```js
const basicRecords = ref([]);

basicRecords.value = recordResult.data
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this variation

```
basicRecords.length = 0;
```

In my case it works for `reactive([])` Vue3 compositionAPI

Comment: This works as "0" -> `number` is a simple type. This won't work for complex types such as object and arrays as `reactive` looks for changes inside complex types.
For simple types us `ref`, there `array.value = []` will work.